# Galois theory basic question

Tags: galois-theory

so as a physicist i have a question about this

if i can draw numerically all the roots in the complex plane, can i get the Galois group of the polynomial

if a equation is sovlable in galois theory does it tell the algorithm or expression to solve the equation ?

Comment: 1. The galois theory only applies for polynomials with integer coefficients (the coefficients can also be rational, this can easily be transformed to an integer polynomials with the same roots). 2. If the galois group is detected to be solvable that does not give us a construction to determine the exact solution by radicals.

Comment: @Peter, actually Galois theory applies even in its basic form to polynomials with coefficients in any field $K$.

Comment: There is an algorithm to find if $f\in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ is solvable and to find the radical expression of the roots. The main step is an algorithm to factorize in irreducibles a polynomial $g\in K[x]$ with $K$ a number field. From repeated factorization and adjunction of roots you get the splitting field and Galois group and adding roots of unity and with Kummer's theorem you get the radical expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Galois group of a polynomial $P(X)$ (in fact the Galois group of its splitting field) is a group of symmetries, but these symmetries can not generally be visualized as symmetries of the complex plane.

For instance for a quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ the Galois transformation $a+b\sqrt{d}\mapsto a-b\sqrt{d}$ is complex conjugation when $d<0$, but doesn't have a clear geometric interpretation when $d>0$ (and $\sqrt{d}\in\mathbb{R}$).

Solvability in terms of Galois theory means that the Galois group has a chain of intermediate subgroups $\{1\}<G_0<G_1<\cdots G_n=G$ where each quotient $G_i/G_{i-1}$ is cyclic. In this case the expression of the roots can be in principle explicitly obtained.